# Process stops after inline script is done via Vagrant

Tags: shell, vagrant, weblogic

In Vagrant, I run an inline script that starts up Weblogic and NodeManager

```
/opt/weblogic/user_projects/domains/custom/startWeblogic.sh &
/opt/weblogic/user_proejcts/domains/custom/bin/startNodeManager &
```

`ps -ef` shows that both processes are running when running the inline script. But if I were to ssh in the guest machine and run `ps -ef`, neither processes are to be found. Is there a way to keep the processes running after the inline script?

Comment: how are you running the script through Vagranfile ? when you run the inline script through ssh, you're running with vagrant user ?

Comment: I use `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/vagrant/scripts/install.sh"` in my VagrantFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you running the script but its executed as `root` user so all the lines are added for this user only. You want to use the [`privileged`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) option

> `privileged` (boolean) - Specifies whether to execute the shell script
>   as a privileged user or not (`sudo`). By default this is "true".

you will want to run the script with the vagrant user so you can change to

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/vagrant/scripts/install.sh",  privileged: false
```

You should then use `nohup` to keep the script running after the session is stopped

```
nohup /opt/weblogic/user_projects/domains/custom/startWeblogic.sh  &> /home/vagrant/startWeblogic.out&
nohup /opt/weblogic/user_proejcts/domains/custom/bin/startNodeManager  &> /home/vagrant/startNodeManager.out&
```

Comment: The processes still do not keep running after the script was executed

Comment: found the problem, the order in my VagrantFile was wrong. I opened my ports after inlining the script.